# Dashboard blocker on network multisite for specific user roles

Tags: functions, multisite

I have used this function below for a while now on normal WordPress installs.

It simply blocks users with specific user roles, and redirects them to the home page of the site.

```
function wpse23007_redirect(){
  if( is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX') && ( current_user_can('subscriber') || current_user_can('media') ) ){
    wp_redirect(home_url());
    exit;
  }
}
add_action('init','wpse23007_redirect');
```

But when I install this on a sub theme in my WordPress Multisite, even though I am a superuser, it is blocking me from the dashboard of my sub theme.

Can anyone help me understand why this is and how to change the above so it doesn't block me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your role checks are relative to the user roles in the sub site in which I assume you are not a user. You should also check for `is_super_admin()`

```
  if( !is_super_admin() && (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX') && ( current_user_can('subscriber') || current_user_can('media') ) ) ){
    wp_redirect(home_url());
    exit;
  }
```